# get_posts and wp_autop (remove filter)

Tags: loop, filters, query-posts, get-posts

I just transformed my query_posts function in a get_posts function.

Here is my old function:

```
<?php
// The Query
query_posts( 'cat=170&showposts=4' );
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');
// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<h3 style="font-size:14px"><a href="';the_permalink(); echo '" title="';the_title(); echo '"> '; the_title(); echo '</a></h3> <div class="ultimipostexcerpt">'; the_excerpt(); echo '</div>';
endwhile;
// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Here's my new one

```
    <?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'category' => 170 );
$tag_posts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $tag_posts as $post ) :
      setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <h3 style="font-size:14px"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3><div class="ultimipostexcerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
    <?php endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

The problem is that now the `remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');` directive doesn't work anymore.. I tried putting it before and after get_posts( $args );, doesn't affect the output.. :( how can I remove the filter for get_posts too?

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own excerpt function:

```
    function wpse125086_custom_strip_tags_excerpt() {
        global $post;
        $p_obj = get_post($post->ID);
        $p_exp = $p_obj->post_excerpt;
        $p_exp = apply_filters('the_excerpt', $p_exp);
        $un_p = array("<p>", "</p>");
        $p_exp = str_replace($un_p, "", $p_exp);
        echo $pcont;
    }
```

But generally I'm thinking instead of transforming to `get_posts()` it might be better to go with [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). In this case the standard filter you're using should work just fine.

---

**Edit:**

If it's about the opening/closing `<p></p>` tags, you can just go with [`get_the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt), because it doesn't add those. you have to echo it to print the excerpt out.

```
echo get_the_excerpt();
```